# Overlay with Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know if theres some trick I can do to put the background color over the other elements inside a div.

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is a drag and drop effect which when someone drag some file into the webpage some color will overlay the other attachments with a message "Drop your file here" for example.

I've created a hidden div with absolute position That shows on dragging  and hides on drop. However that doesn't fit me very well because the droparea is not fixed position on the page. Does anyone have any idea how can I accomplish this task. Any idea would be helpful.

**edit**

Other solution I've tryied was to put with hover, but it doesn't overlay the attachments as expected.

```
function ondragAttchment() {
  $( '.lm-compose-maincontainer' ).on( 'dragover', function(){
    $( '#attachment-list' ).addClass( 'lm-compose-ondragover' );
  });
}

function ondropAttchment() {
  $( '#attachment-list' ).on( 'drop', function(){
    $( this ).removeClass( 'lm-compose-ondragover' );
  });
}
```

**sass**

```
.lm-compose-ondragover
  background-color: #ccc
  opacity: 0.9
  border: 2px dashed #fff
```

Comment: provide some code of what you have tried

Comment: Updated the question. Therefore I just want other idea.

Comment: You probably want to look at pseudo elements. e.g. `el:hover:after` and make the pseudo element overlay the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using opacity and a hex color, try using RGBA, e.g.:

```
rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5); /* #CCC with 0.5 alpha */
```

You can also play around with ::before

https://jsfiddle.net/ys4q5a41/